# How to disable scary terminal commands?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal

How do you disable scary terminal commands?

I was using SSH to access a remote Ubuntu server without access to the physical server. I thought I was typing '`shutdown`' into the NoSQL server running on the Ubuntu OS, but actually I told the Ubuntu server to shutdown. Then I had to tell the server admin what I did so that he could start up the physical server for me. That was embarrassing!

How can I keep this from happening again?

Comment: This has been discussed in lengths, usually with relation to `rm` which has worse side effects than `shutdown`. Bottom line: here is no way to prevent bad things from happening if you keep running random commands as root.

Comment: As other people have noted regarding aliasing, doing so can make people "get in the habit of a command working in a non-standard way." So does it seem bad to anyone else that the silly NoSQL server uses this command?

Comment: The NoSQL server that I was using is Redis.

Comment: Just do not work under the root account.

Comment: I dare say you learnt the lesson so won't have to feel the need to disable any command again. I'd also add you don't fool-proof GNU/Linux, you just get better than the fool.

Comment: permissions .........

Comment: Not working under root account only works if the passwords are different on different servers.  If different servers all have the same passwords, then the wrong system can still be shutdown.

Comment: Ever thought about just... Not executing them?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The standard answer is "don't login as root". All commands run as root are scary. If that isn't an option you could put some alias commands into your `.bashrc` to disable commands you find especially scary. For example:

```
for scary in shutdown halt  reboot rm
do
    alias $scary="echo If you really want to do that, type: `which $scary`"
done
```

Then, if you type shutdown you will get the following message:

```
If you really want to do that, type: /sbin/shutdown
```

(**Make sure** your `.bashrc` has loaded first, **before you try this** on a production server)

Quitting your current `ssh` session and logging in again, or using `. ~/.bashrc` should load/run .bashrc. Perhaps try running `rm` without any arguments to make sure your server hasn't disabled automatically loading `.bashrc` on logins or similar.

Note that if you are primarily concerned with halt and shutdown, you could consider installing [molly-guard](https://packages.debian.org/sid/molly-guard), which will make you type the hostname before shutting down the machine. This is more useful if you regularly shutdown whole OS'es on the commandline, but want to make sure you are shutting down the right one.

You could also test try this with a less scary command such as logout or exit.

Comment: _don't login as root_: this won't help if you're confusing the machine you're logged into. I'd suggest [changing the prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt) to something that would give you a visual cue.

Comment: Aliasing "scary" commands to have a "safe" behaviour is, in my experience, a bad idea. This is because people tend to get in the habit of a command working in a non-standard way which can make them do some very regrettable things when they are on a vanilla system. Simple answer is to tread very carefully when logged in as root.

Comment: @isanae The shortcut I used to open a terminal with ssh to the production server would make the terminal background light red. That made me pay attention.

Comment: You can also use `\shutdown` instead of `/sbin/shutdown` to get around the alias (in bash, at least).

Comment: `source` is an alias to `.` and is not supported by all shells.

Comment: @TimGJ That is very sensible. I wouldn't recommend disabling most commands. When you want to it is nice to know how, just so long as you use discretion.

Comment: Try working as root with two or three screens worth of clusterssh, smallest readable font.Then you'll know what scary is.

Comment: @isanae I read recently about someone whose production root shell was a nice 5-line ascii art warning that it was a root terminal on production. I'm a fan of that kind of thing.

Comment: Also note that while Debian and, by extension, Ubuntu have the defaullt `~/.bash_profile` source `.bashrc`, that isn't standard behavior and on most systems, `.bashrc` is not read when logging in via ssh, so this won't make a difference there. It is far better to add the aliases to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: @terdon Aliases aren't inherited by child processes, and they are intended to be used in interactive shells. `.bashrc` is *exactly* where they belong. It's a good idea to add something like `[[ $- = *i* ]] && source .bashrc` to the end of `.bash_profile` to ensure `.bashrc` is sourced for interactive login shells.

Comment: @isanae I have the .bashrc change the colour of the terminal when I ssh in.

Comment: @isanae So much that. I once sat next to someone who accidentally forkbombed a production server while they thought they were using their own machine… That was a slow and painful realisation. And the reason why I have ``☢prod☢`` in red on the right side of prompts on production servers :)

Comment: @TimGJ I don't get how an error message like "you cannot use shutdown" when you type shutdown gets people in the habit of typing shutdown.

Comment: @MrLister : The problem is when people get in the habit of expecting hand holding, and they come across a system where it hasn't been done.  Decades ago, I worked for our university's main computing center, and we did no such hand-holding.  The engineering department had aliased `rm` to `rm -i`.  So someone came along, and typed `rm *`, thinking it would prompt them for which files to delete .... and lost everything in that directory.

Comment: @MrLister The question was about scary commands in general, not shutdown specifically. So I have some across some sites which alias `rm` ro `rm -i`. Dumb.

Comment: @chepner yes, of course they are not inherited and are meant to be used in interactive shells (well, that's tweakable, but never mind). That's no reason to have `.bashrc` source `.profile`. There are very good reasons to keep the two separate and I dislike this new trend that has them joined.

Comment: You have my suggestion backwards. `.bash_profile` should source `.bashrc`. Further, `.profile` shouldn't be sourcing anything specific to `bash`.

Comment: Much more annoying is habitually typing "halt" and expecting it to behave like "poweroff" (which it stopped doing on some distributions, eg ubuntu).

Comment: "Make sure your .bashrc has loaded first," can .bashrc have something like echo "Safety turned on for $scary commands"?

Answer (score 73):

`sudo` exists for a reason - use it.
When your command (in this case an interactive CLI) is finished, you're dumped back to your user-level shell, not a root shell. There are very few worthy reasons to be in a root shell. (I'm surprised that this isn't already an answer...)

Having said that, don't be a muppet that uses `sudo` for **everything**. Understand what you're doing, and understand why it does/doesn't require root privileges.

---

Additionally you can differentiate your prompt for root / user shells.
This also makes it more obvious that you're back at the shell prompt and not "*some other CLI*". Mine is very colorful, and has lots of useful information (such as the hostname), which makes it *very* simple to know what host the command will execute on, and also makes it easier to look back through your history and locate prompts - a root shell uses the default prompt.

[image: My PS1]

This is more suitable to use on "*your*" account, but if you're taking security/sysadminning seriously, then you won't be sharing passwords/accounts, and you won't be sitting in a root shell without being fully aware.

---

As people have said over, and over, and over again "*aliasing commands to make a safe environment is a bad idea*". You're going to get comfortable in your safe environment, typing those 'scary' commands where you shouldn't. Then one day you'll change jobs, or login to a new machine, and then boom "*whoopsy, I didn't mean to, I'm sorry*"...

Comment: [`sudo` it's your turn to get the coffee.](http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/bizarre_cathedral_95/)

Comment: No, it's about "using `sudo` for everything".

Comment: Wouldn't he have the same problem with `sudo shutdown`? If he executes it on the wrong machine, it  will still be a disaster.

Comment: Yes, but at least he's expecting it to work... Running a command like that on "_the wrong machine_" is a mistake that is trivial to avoid...

Comment: @Barmar Does NoSQL understand the sudo command?

Comment: @Taemyr `sudo` is a shell command, it has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: @Attie I thought that was the whole point -- he ran `shutdown` on the server when he intended to run it on the client, because he forgot he was in a `ssh` shell. He wants to configure something on the server to catch the mistake.

Comment: @Barmar - no need - setup a nice prompt like I showed in my answer, then the hostname is in your face. Also, don't run commands like `shutdown` in a random terminal... make a fresh one - problem solved.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually I think the OP meant to type it into a NoSQL cmdline program, not into bash.  So they wouldn't have typed `sudo shutdown`, since I assume `sudo` isn't a NoSQL command.  Not being in a root shell would have totally solved that problem and been a very good idea.  So would looking at the prompt carefully before running important commands.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you're going to link to a `sudo` cartoon, link to [the original, *definitive* `sudo` cartoon](https://xkcd.com/149 "Make me a sandwich.") (at xkcd, of course).

Answer (score 44):

The package 'molly-guard' (at least on Debian derived systems) will install a wrapper around shutdown, halt, poweroff, and reboot. If it detects that the terminal is a remote one, then it will prompt for the host's name. If it doesn't match, then the command is cancelled.

Comment: what about other (arguably more scary) things like `rm -rf /`?

Comment: @marcellothearcane `set -u` might help with that in some cases, like when writing `rm -rf /$SOME_VARIABLE_WHICH_I_THOUGHT_EXISTS_BUT_DOESNT`.

Comment: @marcellothearcane On anything resembling a modern Linux system, that needs `--no-preserve-root` which you are unlikely to type by accident.

Comment: who's Molly, I wonder...probably someone's cat.

Comment: @the0ther, a 2 year old kid, who triggered the SCRAM switch on a dinosaur machine, twice in the same day.
They folks in the room rigged a cover on the switch.

http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/molly-guard.html

Comment: @CSM that's some nice computer-nerd anthropology there bud. thanks!

Comment: @marcellothearcane That's covered by the "don't run as root" advice, since you'll never run *that* command intentionally, and are likely to be extra careful when typing anything similar.  But `sudo shutdown -h now` is a perfectly normal thing to type on a laptop and a horrible thing to type on a remote server, so having it check if you *are* on a remote connection isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

I accepted an answer that I like a lot, however, if anyone else is reading and want a simpler answer, here is mine.

Find the .bashrc file and put as the last line:

```
alias shutdown=notforuse
```

Then when you type shutdown you get something like `~bash: notforuse is not a command`

This might be silly but it is simple and it works. I do appreciate answers with better ways to do this however!

Comment: Hm, I used to do this with `rm` to troll people - `alias rm='echo "You can't use rm!" #'`

Comment: I think this is a bad idea, for three reasons. First, it's confusing for anybody else who has root access to the machine. Second, it trains you that it's OK to type "shutdown" and hit enter, which means you're likely to make the same mistake on the next system you have root access to. Third, this will become extremely confusing if there's ever a valid command called `notforuse` on the path.

Comment: I'm with @DavidRicherby on this one. Not a good idea.

Comment: If you really want to use the aliases, you can at least put all those _scaring command_ aliases in a file, let we say `~/.SaveMyReputation` and add as last line of your `.bashrc` a line as `[ -f ~/.SaveMyReputation ] && source ~/,SaveMyReputation`. You may want eventually to add an extra line `echo "#Scaring command protected shell, comment the last line of .bashrc and log again to have a full working shell"` inside that file. At least you may bring with you this alias file on other machine (it should be `.bash_aliases`, but in this _"deprecated"_ case is better to use another name).

Comment: If you're going to do this, make it less confusing by using a name like `alias shutdown=shutdown-disabled-by-an-alias`.   (This only addresses the 3rd and most minor problem that @DavidRicherby pointed out.)  Although it will still probably only take 2 seconds for the next person to go from seeing `notforuse is not a command` to running `type -a shutdown` and finding the alias, then typing `sudo \shutdown` to disable alias expansion.  (Assuming they had `sudo` aliased to `sudo='sudo '` so it expands aliases in its first arg).

Answer (score 1):

For `shutdown` (`reboot`, `halt` and related): I have a copy with ask me if I'm really sure (and it does nothing anyway). I store such scripts in in `/usr/local/sbin`. On Debian this has priority other `/sbin` (it is the first directory of PATH).

System scripts use full path, so such *hack* prevent me to stopping a remote server instead of local machine (a bad behaviour from *Awesome* WM), but has not other indirect effect, and I can still use them as /sbin/shutdown when really needed.

Comment: Such hacks only work if you apply them to every computer you ever log in to... that is often quite impractical, and you won't find out until it's too late: by typing `shutdown` on a critical system which does *not* have your hack.

Comment: @jpaugh: yeah, it is an hack, and I use it only for my personal servers, where I often logged in, and terminals remain open for too much time. [Note: I use also different color prompts for my personal machines: remote-root, remote-user, local-root, local-user].  For real servers and remote machine, I avoid root and I go root as little as possible, and for sure, without forgetting to exit from them. Just I'm using the my remotes as "cloud" (before the cloud hype, so handled on the old way).

Answer (score 1):

The Sudoers file allows a much finer level of granularity than just * 'is allowed to use sudo'*, in particular you can use command aliases to create white lists of groups of commands a particular user or group is restricted to. I have worked with remote servers that were restricted to ssh access and allowed password-less sudo (we did require password protected ssh keys). There are some good reasons for doing this, but it does have dangers, so we used command aliases to allow unrestricted access to things they need to do (restarting servers etc) without granting them privileges for thing they didn't.

There is also syntax to say *'can't run this command'*. It can be worked around, so it shouldn't be used as a real security measure but it would work for the scenario you described.

Man sudoers has some good examples on how to set this all up.

Of course this requires using sudo, but that should go without saying.

Answer (score 1):

You may have fallen victim to some new Ubuntu stupidity.

Ubuntu used to have the normal, classic `shutdown` command which takes a mandatory time argument.

Here is what happens on Ubuntu 12 if I type `shutdown`, even as a regular user:

```
$ shutdown
shutdown: time expected
Try `shutdown --help' for more information.
```

Then

```
$ shutdown +100
shutdown: need to be root.
```

Now, here is Ubuntu 16.10. I'm not root:

```
$ date ; /sbin/shutdown
Fri Jun 23 16:00:16 PDT 2017
Shutdown scheduled for Fri 2017-06-23 16:01:16 PDT, use 'shutdown -c' to   cancel.
```

With no arguments, it schedules a shutdown for 60 seconds later, and even if you're not root—just an account made with admin privileges.

Blame Canonical.

Comment: `/sbin/shutdown` [is provided by `systemd-sysv` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/systemd-sysv/filelist) by default, so it's not Ubuntu stupidity, it's `systemd` stupidity, and it comes not from Ubuntu, but from Debian at least, which, in turn, seems to take the whole `systemd` movement from Red Hat. When blaming, blame the correct entity — not just the one you dislike.

Comment: @Ruslan Nobody who packages this crap into their distro escapes the blame of stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

For shutdown there is molly-guard. You just need to install it and when you try to shutdown via ssh, it asks you to type the hostname.

For deleting files there are solutions like libtrash, which emulates a trash bin via a `LD_PRELOAD` library.

And you can test what files you're changing/deleting/... with the [maybe](https://github.com/p-e-w/maybe) program. That's pretty cool when testing something.

Comment: This `maybe` thing seems to be broken by design: stubbing some syscalls with no-ops is going to crash any non-trivial program which relies on these syscalls to succeed.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: when you are on a remote shell, every time you are about to type the "return" key, stop for 5 seconds, with your finger hovering on the "return" key, and reread the command you are about to send.  Is it OK?  Are you sure?

This seems harsh, but, on the other hand, we shouldn't be spending a lot of time on remote shells.  We should find all ways to automate our maintenance work so that we rarely, if ever, need to log in to a remote server at all.

Comment: Tried that, not working.  I entered `shutdown`, stopped for 5 seconds, reread command (aloud!) and I am sure it was correct. Then hit enter and the command just executed. So that didn't disable scary commands, I'm afraid. I will try with this finger hovering thing, maybe the distance was too small/large.